# How to access root element's text in Polymer?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm writing an Polymer element that's supposed to be used like this:

```
<x-elem>Some text</x-elem>
```

The element would transform the text content. But when I try to access it in `attached` callback, it's empty:

```
attached: function() {
    var text = this.root.textContent;
    console.log(text); // Outputs ''
}
```

Frankly, the number of all child nodes is 0:

```
attached: function() {
    console.log(this.root.childNodes.length); // Outputs 0
}
```

According to [these docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#strip-whitespace) I would think that at least my attempt at getting child nodes is correct, but apparently I do something wrong here. Perhaps I need to put something in my template (right now it's simple `<template></template>`, but it is not clear what.

Comment: Don't you access the children of a tag with Polymer.dom(this.$.contentNode)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.root` provides access to the element's **local DOM** (i.e., the DOM locally declared in the `<dom-module>`'s template), but you're trying [to access *light DOM*](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#light-dom-children) (i.e., the DOM passed in). Use `Polymer.dom(this).textContent` for that:

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    attached: function() {
      console.log('textContent:', Polymer.dom(this).textContent);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo>hello world</x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```